# How to retrieve selected RadioButton of dynamic generated RadioButtons in WPF Mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Using WPF and MVVM pattern, I got a Listbox dynamically filled with Radio Buttons.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SupportedNtgs}"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent">                
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <RadioButton GroupName="SupportedNtgsRadioButtonList" Content="{Binding Item2}" />
             </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and in my ViewModel i got a property

```
    public Ntg SelectedNtg
    {
        get { return VariantInfo.Ntg; }

        set
        {
            if (VariantInfo.Ntg == value) { return; }

            VariantInfo.Ntg = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedNtg");
        }
    }
```

The `SupportedNtgs` the ListBox is bound to is an `IEnumerable`

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<Ntg, String>> SupportedNtgs
{
        get
        {
            if (this.supportedNtgs == null) {
                this.supportedNtgs = new List<Tuple<Ntg, string>>();

                foreach (var item in this.provider.SupportedNtgs) {
                    this.supportedNtgs.Add(new Tuple<Ntg, string>(item, EnumHelper<Ntg>.Description(item)));
                }
            }

            return this.supportedNtgs;
        }
}
```

Can anybody tell me what is the easiest way to store the user selection in my SelectedNtg property, without making any changes to my Ntg class? Thank you

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go

- added binding to SelectedItem with SelectedNtg `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNtg}"`

your xaml

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SupportedNtgs}" 
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNtg}" >                
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <RadioButton GroupName="SupportedNtgsRadioButtonList" 
                          Content="{Binding Item2}" />
         </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

this will push the selected item to your property in your view model hence u'll get the data you are looking for

Comment: did you test this? Something isnt working, when putting a breakpoint in the setter of SelectedNtg Property, the debugger wont stop when switching the selection in the ui.

Comment: it should work as long as you have a public property named SelectedNtg in the same datacontext as SupportedNtgs. additionally you may check any binding error in output pane while running the application.

Comment: I have that property and theres no output error. I Also tried Mode=TwoWay, but that doesnt fix the problem aswell. strange

Comment: i just notice that your ienumerable is of type Tuple<Ntg, String> so perhaps `SelectedNtg should be of type Tuple<Ntg, String>`, see if that work for you.

Comment: I figured that out too, it should work if i change it like you suggest. But theres also another problem: the SelectedItem Attribute will bind the selected item and not the item which radiobutton is checked. I think a ListBox is the wrong control for this purpose. I Will try ItemControl, add a bool to my tuple and bind that bool to the ischecked attribute of a radiobutton.